# Is it a good idea to assign NULL to a column of data frame instead of subsetting?

Tags: r, dataframe, null, subset

Let's assume a have `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1 : 3, B = 2 : 4, C = 3 : 5, D = 4 : 6)
```

Now I want to remove column `A` from `df`, the way I was taught is to use `subset`ting:

```
df <- df[, c("B", "C", "D")]
# or
df <- subset(df, select = -A)
```

However, I learned today that this following code can work too:

```
df$A = NULL
```

Which brings me to ask this question:

Is it a good idea to assign `NULL` to a column of data frame instead of subsetting?

What is the implicit difference (E.x. semantics, performance) between these two except that `subset` returns a new object?

Comment: With subsetting, you get another data.frame, while the original stays unchanged (in your case of course you assign the new result to the same name, so the original is lost). With assignment, you modify the data.frame (this isn't internally quite accurate, but it is from the user's point of view) and you lose the column.

Comment: So, if you want another data.frame while keeping the original, you subset. If you want to modify the data.frame, you delete the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to explore it with `tracemem`, `address` and `mem_change`.

Different methods:

```
#subset
my_df <- subset(my_df, select = -A)
```

```
# <- NULL
my_df$A <-  NULL
```

```
# set from data.table
set(my_df, j = "A", value = NULL)
```

```
# subset with []
my_df <- my_df[, colnames(my_df)[-1]]
```

**The results:**

```
method_name
<memory address from tracemem >
<address of df>
(Possibly tracemem results if object is copied)
memory change when column is deleted
<address of df after column deleted>
```

```
subset
[1] "<0x7f92c1504610>"
[1] "0x7f92c1504610"
-178 kB
[1] "0x7f92c1503a10"
```

subset has different final address (expected as df is replaced)

```
<- NULL
[1] "<0x7f92c17b80e0>"
[1] "0x7f92c17b80e0"
tracemem[0x7f92c17b80e0 -> 0x7f92c1719a90]: eval eval mem_change 
tracemem[0x7f92c1719a90 -> 0x7f92c1746400]: $<-.data.frame $<- eval eval mem_change 
tracemem[0x7f92c1746400 -> 0x7f92c17006c0]: $<-.data.frame $<- eval eval mem_change 
-290 kB
[1] "0x7f92c17312e0"
```

`<- NULL` makes a copy (tracemem results; several copies?), and final address is different

```
set from data.table
[1] "<0x7f92c16227c0>"
[1] "0x7f92c16227c0"
-303 kB
[1] "0x7f92c16227c0"
```

set has the same final address. Even if df is not a data.table, `data.table::set` modifies data.frames (and data.tables) by reference.

```
subset with []
[1] "<0x7f92c165cfa0>"
[1] "0x7f92c165cfa0"
-300 kB
[1] "0x7f92c161e950"
```

subset with [] has also different final address

**full code:**

```
.create_data <- function() {
  suppressWarnings(my_df <-
                     data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000000),
                                       ncol = length(LETTERS))))
  colnames(my_df) <- copy(LETTERS)
  my_df
}

library(pryr)
library(data.table)

  ##### subset
  message("subset")
  my_df  <- .create_data()

  tracemem(my_df)
  address(my_df)

  mem_change(my_df <- subset(my_df, select = -A))

  address(my_df)
  untracemem(my_df)
  rm(my_df)
  invisible(gc())

  ##### <- NULL
  message("<- NULL")
  my_df <- .create_data()

  tracemem(my_df)
  address(my_df)

  mem_change(my_df$A <-  NULL)

  address(my_df)
  untracemem(my_df)
  rm(my_df)
  invisible(gc())

  ##### set from data.table
  message("set from data.table")
  my_df <- .create_data()

  tracemem(my_df)
  address(my_df)

  mem_change(set(my_df, j = "A", value = NULL))

  address(my_df)
  untracemem(my_df)
  rm(my_df)
  invisible(gc())

  ##### subset with []
  message("subset with []")
  my_df <- .create_data()

  tracemem(my_df)
  address(my_df)

  mem_change(my_df <- my_df[, colnames(my_df)[-1]])

  address(my_df)
  untracemem(my_df)
  rm(my_df)
  invisible(gc())
```